# Factory_boy not creating different User objects Django

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am new to Factory_boy with Django. After spending some time I understood how to create a factory for User model.

I am using the default user model and following is my factory. I am using Faker for randomness

```
import factory
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from faker import Faker
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

fake = Faker()

class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        django_get_or_create = ('email',)

    first_name = fake.first_name()
    last_name = fake.last_name()
    email = first_name+"."+last_name+"@gmail.com"
    password = make_password("ojasojas")
    username = first_name+"_"+last_name
```

Now in the django shell

I use UserFactory.create() to crate an user. this works fine. Is it possible to loop through create statement and crate 5 different users? Now when I am doing that I am getting only one user (crated once and 'get' 4 times) as follows. What am I missing?[image]

Comment: and if I remove django_get_or_create = ('email',) statement, running crate statement twice throws Unique Constraint Error

Comment: I tried your code example without Faker, replacing the username line with:

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user' + n,str)

And it worked fine, giving me user0, user1, etc.

I'm not familiar with Faker, but I think you should look at how it is used to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining class attributes for your factory, which get evaluated only when the class is defined. `email = first_name+"."+last_name+"@gmail.com"` will be evaluated once, not each time you call `UserFactory.create()`, hence the unique constraint errors. The usual solution to this is to instead define instance attributes via `__init__()`, but FactoryBoy has their own solution to this:  [lazy attributes](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy#lazy-attributes).

Comment: Well, that solves the unique constraint problem. but still I cannot create different objects with a loop.Thanks

Comment: have you tried something like `for user in UserFactory.build_batch(10): user.save()`?

Comment: I tried that as well but it is not working @mindcruzer

Comment: This was not merely an answer to the problem of uniqueness when using faker, but a great reminder of the way that class attributes behave. +1

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but its a work around I've been using lately.  I set the following Global:

```
NAMES = [factory.Faker('name')._get_faker().name() for i in range(5)]
```

In this case, the above will generate a list of 5 fake names.

NOTE:  this does not guarantee a unique name (as `FuzzyChoice` will just select one from the list).

and within your factory:

```
name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(NAMES).fuzz())
```

Answer (score 0):

FactoryBoy offers `LazyFunction` and `LazyAttribute` classes to achieve this. Difference between them is that you can access other model-factory fields in `LazyAttribute`.

Here is an example:

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        django_get_or_create = ('email',)
    
    @staticmethod
    def gen_email(x):
        return x.first_name + "." + x.last_name + "@gmail.com"
    
    first_name = factory.LazyFunction(fake.first_name)
    last_name = factory.LazyFunction(fake.last_name)
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(gen_email)
    password = make_password("ojasojas")
    username = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: x.first_name + "_" + x.last_name)
```

You can use `lambda` expressions as I've used here for demonstration in making the `username` field 'lazy-evaluated', or create functions (static method) and pass them to `LazyFunction`/`LazyAttribute`.

---

You can read more about these classes in official documentation of Factory Boy:

- [LazyFunction](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#lazyfunction)
- [LazyAttribute](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#lazyattribute)